# I am trying to install MySQL in fedora

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

I am trying to install mysql and when I run the install command it keeps throwing the errors or returns failed to download.

```
[root@fedora rk10]# dnf install mysql-community-server
negativo17 - Nvidia                                                                                                                                           26 kB/s |  50 kB     00:01    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'epel-nvidia':
  - Status code: 404 for https://negativo17.org/repos/nvidia/epel-36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 217.79.184.49)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'epel-nvidia': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL 8.0 Community Server                                                                                                                                    17  B/s |  10  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql80-community':
  - Status code: 404 for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 124.41.245.48)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql80-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Connectors Community                                                                                                                                    16  B/s |  10  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-connectors-community':
  - Status code: 404 for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-connectors-community/fc/36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 124.41.245.48)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-connectors-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
MySQL Tools Community                                                                                                                                         19  B/s |  10  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'mysql-tools-community':
  - Status code: 404 for http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-tools-community/fc/36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml (IP: 124.41.245.48)
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'mysql-tools-community': Cannot download repomd.xml: Cannot download repodata/repomd.xml: All mirrors were tried
Ignoring repositories: epel-nvidia, mysql80-community, mysql-connectors-community, mysql-tools-community
Last metadata expiration check: 0:47:47 ago on Fri Jul 22 17:02:33 2022.
No match for argument: mysql-community-server
Error: Unable to find a match: mysql-community-server
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears the URLs that your repos are pointed to do not actually exist.  Check out the URLS for the first two 'epel-nvidia' and 'mysql80-community':

https://negativo17.org/repos/nvidia/

http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/

I would try modifying your corresponding repo files (/etc/yum.repos.d/(repo filename) for each repo that is failing to include a path that actually exists from each URL.

for instance, in the repo file, try changing:

http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/36/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml

to

http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/35/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml

(NOTE the change from ../fc/36/.. to ../fc/35/..)

Good luck, I hope this helps.

Comment: Graymalkin 
Thanks for replying. I am kind of a noob so where exactly do change those links??
I opened the epel-nvidia.repo and this is a part of what I see:-
name=negativo17 - Nvidia
baseurl=https://negativo17.org/repos/nvidia/epel-$releasever/$basearch/
enabled=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://negativo17.org/repos/RPM-GPG-KEY-slaanesh
enabled_metadata=1
metadata_expire=6h
type=rpm-md
repo_gpgcheck=1

do I change the baseurl??

Comment: Hey Messi10, no worries, fortunately we have a place like stack to ask questions.  Thanks for the repo information. So the issue here is that a repo line appears to be malformed for your version of Fedora (denoted by the /epel-$releasever/ portion of what you sent).  The quick and dirty way to get what you need is by replacing "/epel-$releasever/" with the latest version in the repo which will likely be "/fedora-36/".  You could also possibly try "/epel-9/" which appears to be the latest release for epel.  I'd try fedora-36 first, since that appears to be the version you are on.

Comment: For Mysql, it appears as though there is not a repo for Fedora 36 yet, so I would recommend trying Fedora 35.  Replace the same "baseurl" line in your repo file to reflect 35 rather than 36: "http://repo.mysql.com/yum/mysql-8.0-community/fc/35/x86_64/" (you are replacing the $release with "35").

Additionally, mariadb will likely already have a Fedora 36 repo, you may want to try installing that (mariadb is a fully compatible fork clone of MySQL, developed after Sun was sold to Oracle).